# Azure Bot + WhatsApp integration

Tags: azure-sql-database, chatbot, whatsapp, azure-bot-service

I made the Azure QnA Bot, but I can't figure out how to integrate it with WhatsApp. The purpose of this is to have an automated bot like in WhatsApp Business that allows to choose options, but also be able to type free text to get the info. The info itself would be on Azure SQL Database resource and can be edited and read from it via WhatsApp.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

As you don't list which SDK you are using, it is hard to provide an accurate answer. However, there are two libraries that could potentially meet your needs, both available thru the BotBuilder-Community repos.

- Infobip WhatsApp for Bot Builder v4 (C#, in preview): https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Adapters.Infobip.WhatsApp
- Twilio WhatsApp Adapter (JS, beta): https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-adapter-twilio-whatsapp/src/twilioWhatsAppAdapter.ts

The only other option would be to create a custom built adapter of your own. There are plenty of examples available in those repos that can serve as reference, if needed.